# Null and alternative hypotheses : Car model fuel usage

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Some people assume that a specific car model does at least $\mu_0=120$ km with $1$ Lt of gasoline (petrol).

$10$ independent tests give the following results: $$104, \ 96, \ 80, \ 100, \ 108, \ 100, \ 112, \ 120, \ 130, \ 132$$

(a) Give the Null Hypothesis $H_0$ and the alternative Hypothesis $H_1$, for the test of that assumption.

(b) Give the statistic function of that test.

(c) late the p-value of the test.

(d) In what confidence level can the assumption be rejected?

$$$$

For (a) is the null hypothesis $H_0: \ m_0=120$ and the alternative $H_1: \ \mu_1\neq 120$ ?

Comment: Since you are trying to figure out if the car model gets "at least" 120km, it might make more sense for the alternative hypothesis to be $\mu > 120$

Comment: Ah so is thenull hypothesis $H_0 : \ mu=120$ and the alternative $H_1 : \ mu>120$ ?@Adam

Comment: That is one option.  Both $\mu \neq 120$ and $\mu > 120$ are fine choices for the alternative hypothesis; which choice you make depends on what you care about in the context of the problem

Comment: Ah ok! Could you give me a hint for question (b) ? @Adam

Comment: In the US the fuel usage of automobiles is measured in miles per gallon (MPG) which is a multiple of the reciprocal of km/l. Both methods of measurements cannot be successfully modeled as normal.

Comment: @BruceET : without a Normal assumption I do not think there is a basic way to solve the exercise...am I wrong? moreover I never saw a car doing 120 km with 1 liter gas

Comment: With 10 observations a formal test of normality will be essentially useless. My answer show a normal probability plot that is (roughly) consistent with normality. // I did not claim that either US or metric fuel economy measurements are normal; just that it is logically inconsistent to say that _both_ are normal.// Based on the wording of the problem, I do object to a two-sided test.

Comment: My guess is that you are expected to do a one-sided t test without fretting about possible non-normality, but see why you asked for comments here. // My Answer discusses some alternative options.

Comment: US English it's gas or gasoline; UK petrol. Benzine is something you probably wouldn't put in a car.

Answer (score 1):

- You have to assume normality
- The Hypothesis you stated is correct
- the test statistics is the following

$$t=\frac{\overline{X}_{10}-120}{S}\sqrt{10}\sim \mathcal{T}_{9}$$

say $t$ follows a Student T distribution with 9 d.o.f.

$S^2$ is the unbiased sample variance (to be calculated with the given data)

I think you can conclude by yourself

To calulate exactly the pvalue you need a calculator. It results to me $p_{\text{value}}\approx 4.41\%$

You can reject $H_0$ for any significance level less than $p$

Comment: How do we calculate tje p-value? As for ghe last question, by significance level you mean confidence level? (I wrote at the beginning significance in my post but it was a tyüo, i corrected ot)

Comment: @MaryStar : the $t_{\text{stat}}=-2.33$ You have to calculate the area where $t<-2.33$ plus the area where $t>2.33$. If you do not have a calculator you can't.

Comment: @MaryStar : usually in Hypothesis testing we speak about significance of a test. Confidence level is its complement to 1 but in some texts there is a little confusion. If you state significance level less than 4.41% the answer is understood by everybody

Comment: I think your P-value may be for a two-sided test, which does not seem appropriate here.

Comment: @BruceET yes it is a 2 sided p-value. thanks for your reply

Comment: As per earlier comment I favor a one-sided test, but (+1) for your discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The ten observations 104, 96, 80, 100, 108, 100, 112, 120, 130, 132
have mean $\bar X = 108.2,$ which is less than 120. The question
is whether 108.2 is significantly smaller than 120 in a statistical sense. That is, the question whether to reject
$H_0: \mu \ge 120$ in favor of $H_1: \mu < 120.$

It seems safe to assume the population from which these ten
observations were taken is normal. There are not enough observations for a convincing goodness-of-fit test, but a boxplot shows no outliers and a normal probability
plot is not far from linear. [Plot and test use R.]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 boxplot(x, col="skyblue2")
 qqnorm(x);  qqline(x, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

[image]

It seems safe to do a t.test, which gives P-value $0.02206 < 0.05 = 5\%,$ rejecting $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance. [@tommik gives the formula for the t statistic.]

```
t.test(x, mu=120, alt="less")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -2.3385, df = 9, p-value = 0.02206
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 120
95 percent confidence interval:
   -Inf 117.4499
sample estimates:
mean of x 
    108.2
```

The 5% critical value for this one-sided test is $-1.833 > -2.338;$ another indication to reject at the 5% level.

The exact P-value cannot be found from printed tables, but it can be bracketed between two values (e.g., in my table between 0.01 and 0.025). A direct computation in R is shown below:

```
qt(.05, 9)
[1] -1.833113   # 5% left-sided critical value

pt(-2.3385, 9)
[1] 0.02206428  # consistent with output above
```

If you are expected to show how to compute the t statistic, determine the degrees of freedom, or find the 5% critical
value of the test, I will leave that to you.

*Notes on alternative methods:* (1) If one questions normality, the data seem
sufficiently symmetrical that one might do a one-sample
Wilcoxon signed-rank test for the population *median.*
The P-value $0.025,$ shown below indicates rejection at the 5% level, but there are warning messages
that ties and a data value exactly at 120 prevent the P-value from being exact.

```
wilcox.test(x, mu = 120, alt="less")$p.val
[1] 0.02510388
```

(2) One pivot-quantile style of 95% nonparametric bootstrap one-sided CI is $(-\infty, 116.2),$ which does not include the hypothetical value $120,$ suggesting rejection of $H_0$ at the 5% level. (I say 'suggest' because ten observations may not be enough for a reliable bootstrap CI. An advantage is that the bootstrap does not assume normal data.)

```
a.obs = mean(x)
set.seed(225)
d.re = replicate(5000, mean(sample(x,10,rep=T)-a.obs))
L = quantile(d.re, .05)
a.obs - L
   5% 
116.2
```

(3) A one-sided sign test for median 120 looks at 2 of 9
observations (different from 120) greater than 120 and
gives P-value $0.0898,$ not significant at the 5% level.

```
pbinom(2, 9, .5)
[1] 0.08984375
```

Because the sign test is easy to do as above, the core
of R lacks a formal sign test. Here is output from Minitab:

```
Sign test of median =  120.0 versus < 120.0

    N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
x  10      7      1      2  0.0898   106.0
```

*Note on testing normality in small samples:* With only ten observations it is difficult
to judge normality using a formal test. The Shapiro-Wilk
test is one of the best, but its power against (often skewed) exponential samples is only about 44% and
against (often symmetrical) uniform samples only
about 8%. Consequently, many statisticians
prefer graphical methods (boxplots, normal probability
plots) for judging normality of small samples.

```
set.seed(1234)
pv = replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(rexp(10))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.4424
pv = replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(runif(10))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.0833
```